# Abstracting Connection String out of Entity Framework 6 Consumers

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I think a better post here would be "Abstracting Entity Framework from Entity Framework Consumers". I really like what Entity Framework does and the power it holds. My biggest complaint that I can't seem to work around is that regardless how many layers of abstraction I add, every project that consumes Entity Framework **has** to include `System.Data.Entity`, `EntityFramework.SqlServer` and the `ConnectionStrings` from the base EF layer or else you get an error at runtime.

The image I attached is what we are trying to do on my team to separate concerns:

[image]

I want neither the WebAPI, SignalR or Window Service(s) to need to add `ConnectionStrings` and `EntityFramework` DLLs to their layers. Is there anyway to accomplish this? I keep seeing things on using the Repository pattern, which is great for testing, but I still can't consume an EF layer without including several EF artifacts! Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "including" do you mean adding references or including namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Repository was going to be my answer until I read through to the bottom of the post. Coded "correctly," that pattern helps decouple your code from the ORM technology ("loose coupling"). Ideally, you would have a repository that allows a dependent class to call it without referencing the EntityFramework assemblies. In that case, you should also be able to replace the repository with one that uses a different ORM (e.g. NHibernat, OrmLite, Dapper, etc).